# Can an unused function instantiate a variable template with side-effects according to C++14?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, standards, unused-variables

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyBaseClass
{
public:
    static int StaticInt;
};

int MyBaseClass::StaticInt = 0;

template <int N> class MyClassT : public MyBaseClass
{
public:
    MyClassT()
    {
        StaticInt = N;
    };
};

template <int N> static MyClassT<N> AnchorObjT = {};

class UserClass
{
    friend void fn()
    {
        std::cout << "in fn()" << std::endl; //this never runs
        (void)AnchorObjT<123>;
    };  
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << MyBaseClass::StaticInt << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
123
```

...indicating `MyClassT()` constructor was called despite that `fn()` was never called.

Tested on `gcc` and `clang` with `-O0`, `-O3`, `-Os` and even `-Ofast`

---

### Question

Does this program have undefined behavior according to C++ standard?

In other words: if later versions of compilers manage to detect that `fn()` will never be called can they optimize away template instantiation together with running the constructor?

Can this code somehow be made deterministic i.e. force the constructor to run - *without* referencing function name `fn` or the template parameter value `123` outside of the `UserClass`?

---

**UPDATE:** A moderator truncated my question and suggested further truncation. Original verbose version can be viewed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53683119/1).

Comment: I think the TL;DR form of this question is: "if something is _used_ only by code that's _unused_, is that something _used?_"

Comment: A lot of things not related to each other but makes reading all of this complicated. All of this breaks down to having templates instantiated or not. In a short: Even if a function is not called, it is compiled and all and everything which is needed to make it callable is instantiated.

Comment: Additional complication: **[basic.start.init]** "It is implementation-deﬁned whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage duration is done before the ﬁrst statement of main. If the initialization is deferred to some point in time after the ﬁrst statement of main, it shall occur before the ﬁrst odr-use (3.2) of any function or variable deﬁned in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized." So you cannot rely on dynamic initialization occurring prior to the first statement of `main`. You have to odr-use something from the same translation unit.

Comment: the "my theories" section can probably be removed, it's not really relevant to the question nor the answer

Comment: Understood, deleted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template instantiation is a function of the code, not a function of any kind of dynamic runtime conditions. As a simplistic example:

```
template <typename T> void bar();

void foo(bool b) {
  if (b) {
    bar<int>();
  } else {
    bar<double>();
  }
}
```

Both `bar<int>` and `bar<double>` are instantiated here, even if `foo` is never invoked or even if `foo` is only ever invoked with `true`.

For variable template, specifically, the rule is [[temp.inst]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#inst-6.sentence-1):

> Unless a variable template specialization has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the variable template specialization is implicitly instantiated when it is referenced in a context that requires a variable definition to exist or if the existence of the definition affects the semantics of the program.

In your function:

> ```
> friend void fn() 
> { 
>     (void)AnchorObjT<123>;
> };
> ```

`AnchorObjT<123>` is referenced in a context that requires a definition (regardless of whether `fn()` is ever called or even, in this case, it is even possible to call), hence it is instantiated.

But `AnchorObjT<123>` is a global variable, so its instantiation means we have an object that is constructed before `main()` - by the time we enter `main()`, `AnchorObjT<123>`'s constructor will have been run, setting `StaticInt` to `123`. Note that we do not need to actually run `fn()` to invoke this constructor - `fn()`'s role here is just to instantiate the variable template, its constructor is invoked elsewhere.

Printing 123 is the correct, expected behavior.

---

Note that while the language requires the global object `AnchorObjT<123>` to exist, the linker may still the object because there is no reference to it. Assuming your real program does more with this object, if you need it to exist, you may need to do more to it to prevent the linker from removing it (e.g. gcc has the [`used` attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#index-used-variable-attribute)).

Comment: This answer would be improved by talking about how actual linkers today eliminate "unused" object files.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I'm not sure it's relevant.

Comment: because using almost this exact technique, I had to force a symbol to be used (anywhere in the file) in order to prevent the linker from eliminating the entire compilation unit from my program.  Linkers add object files based on references *to* the obj, not *from* the obj.  So in practice the Op's technique can and does fail.  Which seems relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. It could be greatly improved if you could elaborate on `AnchorObjT<123> is referenced in a context that requires a definition`, i.e. is there anything in the standard that suggests that unused functions' bodies do require definition of their contents?

Comment: @Jack The rules for odr-use don't depend on that - it's a function of what the expression looks like, not a function of whether or not that expression can be evaluated (which probably reduces to the halting problem)

Comment: How does `(void)AnchorObjT<123>;` require the definition to exist?

Comment: @M.M "Printing 123 is the correct, expected behavior" doesn't answer whether or not it's UB?

Comment: Although I'm still unable to find any solid *evidence* that instantiation (or ODR-use) does not depend on function being used, this is as close as we can get, I guess. I'm accepting the answer then.

Answer (score 2):

"If later versions of compilers manage to detect that fn() will never be called [and] they optimize away template instantiation" then those compilers would be broken.

C++ compilers are free to implement any optimization ***that has no observable effect***. In the situation you have outlined there would be at least one observable effect: namely a static class member does not get constructed and initialized, so a C++ compiler cannot completely optimize that away. It won't happen.

A compiler can ignore everything else about the function call, and not actually compile the function call itself, but the compiler must do whatever it needs to do to make arrangements so that the static class member gets initialized ***as if*** that function call was made.

If the compiler can determine that nothing else in the program actually uses the static class member, and removing it completely has no observable effect, then the compiler can remove the static class member, and the function that initializes it (since nothing else references the function).

Note, that even taking an address of a function (or a class member) would result in an observable effect, so even if nothing actually calls the function, but something takes the address of the function, it can't just go away.

P.S. -- all of the above presumes no undefined behavior in the C++ code. With undefined behavior entering the picture, all the rules go out the window.

Comment: I think the question really boils down to this excerpt: "The standard says that template instance is generated if it it _used_. If it is _used_ by something itself _unused_ this **probably** makes it also _unused_." I'm not sure this answer addresses that.

Comment: Note that library linking may eliminate compilation units in practice.

Comment: `compilers are free to implement any optimization that has no observable effect` on standard-compliant code. If the code has any undefined behavior the compiler is free to assume any outcome - this is known to made some programs fail because they were unknowingly relying on undefined behavior that a compiler found and happily optimized away. The question was mainly about *if* this *is* undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is it works.

The long answer is it works *unless* the linker discards your entire translation unit (.obj).

This can happen when you create a .lib and link it.  The linker typically picks which .obj to link from the lib based on a dependency graph of "do I use symbols that obj exports".

So if you use this technique in a cpp file, that cpp files has no symbols that are used elsewhere in your exexutable (including indirectly via other obj in your lib that are in turn used by the executable), the linker may discard yoir obj file.

I have experienced this with clang.  We where creating self registering factories, and some where being dropped.  To fix it we created some macros that caused a trivial dependency to exist, preventing the obj file from being discarded.

This doesn't contradict the other answers, because the process of linking a lib is aboit deciding what is and what is not in your program.

Comment: It might be related to [Deferred dynamic initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization).

Comment: In the case of "the linker discards your entire translation unit", would that mean the implementation is non-conforming?

Comment: @m.m the C++ standard does not specify how ths linker picks which translation units to be included in the program.

Comment: So it is actually unspecified whether OP's code prints `123` or `0` ? (if there were another TU in the program)

Comment: @m.m No: which TU are in the program is not specified by the C++ standard.  I mean, one way is you list .o files on the command line.  Another is you link libraries.  This is all tooling, not C++ itself.  This library linking quirk is that linking a lib into an executable can include only the TU you use symbols from.  If the TU is in the executable it works, if it is eliminated it doesn't.  And that behaviour is far outside of what the C++ standard specifies.  It specifies what happens when the TU are in the program, **not** how they get there.

Comment: Unfortunately "it *works*" is not really equivalent to "it *is supposed to* work" or "it will not suddenly stop working because of a tiny update in compiler code". The linker is not that much of concern here - this can be fixed with linker options. If the compiler stops compiling the code however I would need to completely rework syntax of my library usage which would require a lot of code that uses it to be rearranged with potential easy-to-miss mistakes so a lot of testing too.